# Is it possible to make a function with multiple parameters of different types take the parameters in any order without overloading?

Tags: c#, function, parameter-passing

Say for example if a have a function that takes 3 parameters of all different types:

```
public void myFunction (int myInt, double myDouble, bool myBool)
{
    //Some code here
}
```

Can it be made, without overloading, to be called passing the parameters in any order?

```
myFunction(aBool, anInt, aDouble);
myFunction(aDouble, aBool, anInt);
etc..
```

Comment: Not in the way you show, but you can reference the parameters to set by their names which IIRC allows you to then specify them in arbitrary order.

Comment: short from something hacky like `public void myFunction(object[] args){}` - not really..

Comment: You can make a use of parameter names, see the example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  private void OperationOverLoadTest()
        {
            this.myFunction(1, 1.1D, true);
            this.myFunction(myDouble: 1.1D, myBool:false, myInt:1);

        }

        public void myFunction(int myInt, double myDouble, bool myBool)
        {
            //Some code here
        }
```

Comment: OP asked for a way to do this without overloading.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it directly. There are some options:

You can use named parameters to allow arbitrary order. This will preserve static type checking.

```
 myFunction(myBool:aBool, myInt:anInt, myDouble:aDouble);
```

You can use `params` and lose type checking. You'll need to check types of arguments passed in. This is how JavaScript often implements functions with variable number of arguments:

```
public void myFunction (params object[] args)
{
    int myInt = args.OfType<int>().FirstOrDefault();
    ...
}

 myFunction(2.4, false, 3);
```

Comment: is that not `params object[] args` ?